# Como redireccionar a mis redes sociales con ionic?

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hice un toolBar y dentro puse un presentActionSheet, en cada uno quería poner una red social mía distinta, y que al clickearlo se redireccione a esa pagina web. Que función debo hacer?

```
const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
  header: 'Opciones',
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Cerrar Sesion',
    role: 'destructive',
    icon: 'hand',
    handler: () => {
      this.OnLogout();
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'Mi GitHub',
    role: 'destructive',
    icon: 'logo-github',
    handler: () => {
      //-------------------
     //-- AQUI VA LA URL ej: https://gitHub.com/xxxx
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un plugin nativo de Ionic que es Social Sharing.

La documentación esta muy clara para lo que necesitas saludos.

[DOC](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#5-web-share-api)

[Social Sharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing)